# Trying to block/allow certain characters in input by ascii code

Tags: jquery, utf-8, ascii

I am trying to allow numerical characters and hyphen using on keydown. The ascii code for hyphen should be 45, but when I press it or underscore, it says 189. The top of my page has charset=utf-8, but the ascii characters for the letters and numbers is correct, just not special characters. And the special characters also don't match ascii or utf-8 .. Is there any way to check what character encoding is being used or have a better way of doing this? Help greatly appreciated

```
<script>
//allow alphanumeric and dash
$("#title.mgrid_text").on("keydown",function(e){
     console.log(e.which);
if((e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) || e.which == 45 || (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57 )){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, had to use on keypress not keydown/up